# How I can ignore the change event with jQuery when clicking on a different element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#playerSelect').on('click', 'li.playerName', function() {
        alert("playerSelect click " + $(this).text());
    });
    $('#newName').change(function() {
        alert("newName change " + $('#newName').val());
    });
});
<ul id="playerSelect">
    <li><input type="text" id="newName" value="New Player"" autofocus autocomplete="off" /></li>
    <li class='playerName'>Bill</li>
    <li class='playerName'>Joe</li>
</ul>
```

With this code, if I enter anything in the input field, then change my mind and click a `.playername` button, the change event occurs. But I want the click event.

Comment: here is the demo fiddle with your code - https://jsfiddle.net/shershen08/3wnLocop/, what you want to achieve? when you change the input you get the alert with input, when you click the button you get the value of the button.

Comment: I want to register the click event, even if the input field has been changed.

Comment: you want to display this alert "playerSelect click ..." on  input field change you mean?

Comment: Yes. Basically I want to totally ignore any change to the input if a playerSelect button is clicked on.

Comment: Unfortunately, this code doesn't do it either. It doesn't capture the change event at all when the user changes the input and hits, for instance, the "Enter" key. If I add the .change code back in, I'm back to square one. It seems that the change event occurs first, before anything else however I trigger it (change, blur, lostfocus). I'd think it was impossible, but Google does it on every search results page!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, can you try this code then:

```
function displayDetails(){
        alert("newName change " + $('#newName').val());
}
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#playerSelect').on('click', 'li.playerName', function() {
        displayDetails();
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm a beaten man! The only workaround that I can find is to use keyup/keydown instead of .change, and manually test for keycode 13 (or a click on the input field). At least I can get what I want that way. And a big thank you for your help.